# How to Rename a Renamed file if already exist in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to rename files before moving to another subfolder. The first thing I do is to get the filenames and extensions of the files on the LOCATION FOLDER. After that I check whether those files exist on the ACTIVE FOLDER. If yes I renamed it by adding incremented integer.

For instance LOCATION FOLDER contains 'sample.txt' file and ACTIVE FOLDER has no file like that. On that case I don't need to rename the file 'sample.txt', all I need to do is to move it to ACTIVE FOLDER. But when ACTIVE FOLDER contains such filename, when moved it must be renamed as sample(1).txt, and when another file on LOCATION FOLDER has filename 'sample.txt' when moved must be sample(2).txt.

Below is my code

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION")
    Dim Folder1Files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()

    For Each nFile As FileInfo In Folder1Files

        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nFile.Name)
        Dim fileExt As String = Path.GetExtension(nFile.Name)
        Dim newFileName As String
        Dim fileNumber = 0


        If File.Exists("C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION\ACTIVE FOLDER\" & fileName & fileExt) Then

            fileNumber += 1
            newFileName = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}", fileName, fileNumber, fileExt)


            File.Move("C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION\" & fileName & fileExt, "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION\ACTIVE FOLDER\" & newFileName)

        Else
            File.Move("C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION\" & fileName & fileExt, "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION\ACTIVE FOLDER\" & fileName & fileExt)
        End If


    Next


End Sub
```

Whenever I tried to debug above code, and 'sample.txt' exist when moved it becomes 'sample(1).txt', therefore it's correct, but when 'sample.txt' exist again on LOCATION FOLDER when moved it becomes 'sample(1)(1).txt', where in fact it must be 'sample(2).txt'.

What should I do to get my expected result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try without doing the adding operation- just leave fileNumber as 1. Don't increment it by 1.

Comment: it doesn't work sir...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try with this code and excuse if there is any syntax error as I've converted my code from C# to VB.

```
Dim oldDir As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION"
Dim newDir As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION\ACTIVE FOLDER\"
Dim newFileName As String = String.Empty
Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(oldDir)
Dim Folder1Files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()

For Each nFile As FileInfo In Folder1Files
   Dim oldFileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nFile.Name)
   Dim fileExt As String = Path.GetExtension(nFile.Name)
   Dim oldPath As String = oldDir & oldFileName & fileExt
   Dim newPath As String = newDir & oldFileName & fileExt
   Dim index As Integer = 1

   While File.Exists(newPath)
       newFileName = oldFileName & "(" & index & ")"
       newPath = newDir & newFileName & fileExt
       index += 1
   End While

   File.Move(oldPath, newPath)
Next
```

I hope it gives you a better clue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\LOCATION")
Dim Folder1Files As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()

For Each nFile As FileInfo In Folder1Files

    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nFile.Name)
    Dim fileExt As String = Path.GetExtension(nFile.Name)
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim fileNumber = 0

    string pathAndFileName = dir & Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & fileName
    string fileExtension = "." & fileExt

    ' if file exists then add a file counter at the end of the file name
    int fileNumber  = 1
    while (File.Exists(pathAndFileName & fileExtension))        ' Check if the file already exists
    {
        string fileNameConcatenationStr = "_" & String.Format("{0:0000}", fileNumber )      ' The file name format will be something like --> FileName_0001.csv
        pathAndFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathAndFileName) & Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & fileName & fileNameConcatenationStr & Path.GetExtension(pathAndFileName)     ' Insert the _0001 string into the file name and path.
        fileNumber += 1
    }

    ' Do your file move here using pathAndFileName & fileExtension
    File.Move(....)




Next
```